# Laravel retrieve deleted users multiple times

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my application, I have a button for deleting the account.

This is the function code:

```
    public function deleteAccount()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        auth()->logout();
        request()->session()->invalidate();
        request()->session()->regenerateToken();
        $user->delete();

        return redirect(route('login'))->with([
            'status' => __('Your account has been deleted')
        ]);
    }
```

I signed in with the same account with the "Remember" option on both Edge and Firefox browsers. When I click "Delete Account" on Edge, Laravel also dismisses me on Firefox because it deleted my account.

The problem is: On Firefox, Laravel is still trying to retrieve my account with Session and Cookies info because it hasn't been updated. And it runs again and again everywhere I use the auth() function.

[image: sill-retrieve-deleted-user]

How to avoid this? Or how do other sessions know that their information is out of date?
(I think it should only check once, like when it finds a user)

Demo code: https://github.com/tungwoodboi/demo-laravel-deleted-user

I found this in the SessionGuard class:

```
    public function user()
    {
        if ($this->loggedOut) {
            return;
        }

        // If we've already retrieved the user for the current request we can just
        // return it back immediately. We do not want to fetch the user data on
        // every call to this method because that would be tremendously slow.
        if (! is_null($this->user)) {
            return $this->user;
        }

        $id = $this->session->get($this->getName());

        // First we will try to load the user using the identifier in the session if
        // one exists. Otherwise we will check for a "remember me" cookie in this
        // request, and if one exists, attempt to retrieve the user using that.
        if (! is_null($id) && $this->user = $this->provider->retrieveById($id)) {
            $this->fireAuthenticatedEvent($this->user);
        }

        // If the user is null, but we decrypt a "recaller" cookie we can attempt to
        // pull the user data on that cookie which serves as a remember cookie on
        // the application. Once we have a user we can return it to the caller.
        if (is_null($this->user) && ! is_null($recaller = $this->recaller())) {
            $this->user = $this->userFromRecaller($recaller);

            if ($this->user) {
                $this->updateSession($this->user->getAuthIdentifier());

                $this->fireLoginEvent($this->user, true);
            }
        }

        return $this->user;
    }
```

Comment: So your account is deleted so authentication fails. You should then redirect to the login page if you aren't logged in, not repeatedly fire try the same route

Comment: @BenGooding What you said is only true for the user session that submitted the request to delete the account. We can't redirect to the login page for another session because they are browsing a page that doesn't require login.